# Jquery checkbox max checked

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

for some reason my code is not working proprly, it should disable the checkboxes when lenght is > than 5 . Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var $checks = $(".bowling").change(function () {
        if ($checks.filter(":checked").length<=5)
        {
            $(".formular").toggle($checks.filter(":checked").length>0);
            $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $(".formular").offset().top});
        }
        else
        {
            $checks.filter(":checked").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });
</script>
```

html it's in a while:

```
<label class="ora_bg" data-toggle="tooltip" data-trigger="click hover" data-placement="bottom" >    
    <input class="bowling" type="checkbox" value="'.$row['Interval'].'" name="interval[]" class="checkbox" id="i'.$row['Interval'].'">
    <h3 class="ora2_bg">'.$row['Interval'].'</h3>
</label>
```

Comment: Have you removed the document ready handler to make the example shorter? If not, you need one.

Comment: lenght of unchecked checkbox is 5 or checked?

Comment: use .prop() to set the checked state like `$checks.filter(":checked").prop("disabled", true);`

Comment: in checkbox change event when checked length=5 then add disabled attribute to all unchecked checkboxes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var $checks = $(".bowling").change(function () {
  if ($checks.filter(":checked").length<=5)
  {
    $checks.not(":checked").prop("disabled", false);
  }
  else
  {
    $checks.not(":checked").prop("disabled", true);;
  }
});
```

**Demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/hM8kP/2/

Comment: seems .not is the winning answer :d, thnx it's working

Comment: hmm but it's an error, after i uncheck a box i cant check another one :-?

Comment: i have created an dummy example gor you , just check downside 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24883654/jquery-checkbox-max-checked/24884066#24884066

Comment: @user3058067, I have updated my answer. Please check.

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me on jsFiddle:

```
<input class="bowling checkbox" type="checkbox" value="" type="checkbox" />
<input class="bowling checkbox" type="checkbox" value="" type="checkbox" />
<input class="bowling checkbox" type="checkbox" value="" type="checkbox" />
<input class="bowling checkbox" type="checkbox" value="" type="checkbox" />
<input class="bowling checkbox" type="checkbox" value="" type="checkbox" />
<input class="bowling checkbox" type="checkbox" value="" type="checkbox" />
<input class="bowling checkbox" type="checkbox" value="" type="checkbox" />


$(document).ready(function(){    // I have just added this
    var $checks = $(".bowling").change(function () {
        if ($checks.filter(":checked").length<=5)
        {

            $checks.not(":checked").removeAttr("disabled");
            $("html, body").animate({scrollTop: $(".formular").offset().top});
        }
        else
        {
            $checks.not(":checked").attr("disabled", "disabled");
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var $checks = $(".bowling").change(function () {
    if ($checks.filter(":checked").length < 5)
    {
        $(".formular").toggle($checks.filter(":checked").length>0);
        // enable all inputs
        $checks.not(":checked").removeAttr("disabled");
    }
    else
    {
        $checks.not(":checked").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    }
});
```

THIS WORKS FINE FOR ME

### [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/MHq52/)

Answer (score 0):

Here as you have not provided your markup , i hav created an dummy example for you which might fulfill your requirement

[click here to view your example](http://jsfiddle.net/rKe5g/1/)

```
$(function(){
    $("input[type='checkbox']").on('click', function(){
           alert($("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").length);
        if($("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").length <=1 ){
            $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").attr('disabled', true);
        }else{
            $("input[type='checkbox']").attr('disabled', false);

            var checked = $("input[type='checkbox']:checked");

            if(checked.length >0)
            {
                var value = checked.val();
                $("input[name='banners_image_local']").val(value);    
            }
        }     
    });
});
```